# why I got this error "I couldn't open file name `build\main.aux'"

Tags: bibtex, report, bbl

I really appreciate any help. after running the file, I got this error "I couldn't open file name `build\main.aux'"
I read the same questions and try to solve my problem but unfortunately, I couldn't. I attach my code. I m trying to write my thesis :(

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[numbers,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[top = 3 cm, bottom = 2.5 cm, left = 2.5 cm, right = 3 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
%\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN
\etex_iffontchar:D
\tex_iffontchar:D
\cs_undefine:N \c_one
\int_const:Nn \c_one { 1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\settextfont[Scale=1]{Yas}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1.1]{Yas}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{harfi}
\tableofcontents
\doublespacing
\doublespacing


\include{chapters/2-chap}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt-fa}
\bibliography{mybibliography}{}



\end{document}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% and the bibliography file

```
@article{Wootters1982,
    author={Wootters, W. K.
    and Zurek, W. H.},
    title={A single quantum cannot be cloned},
    journal={Nature},
    year={1982},
    month={Oct},
    day={01},
    volume={299},
    number={5886},
    pages={802-803},
    abstract={},
    issn={1476-4687},
    doi={10.1038/299802a0},
    url={https://doi.org/10.1038/299802a0}
}
```

%%%%%%%%%%% and chapter folder file

```
\cite{Wootters1982}.
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
very thanks in advance

Comment: you presumably used a commandline to tell xelatex to write aux files to a build directory when no such directory exists, or is not writable.

Comment: Thank you David, but what command? How can I fix it!  Also thanks for editing my question and sorry about that.

Comment: David, your comment is very helpful. my problem is solved. I really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

you presumably used a commandline such as

```
xelatex --output-directory=build  myfile.tex
```

to tell xelatex to write files to a build directory when no such directory exists, or is not writable. If you just use the standard command with no such output argument then the aux file (and other files) will be written to the current directory.

Comment: Very thanks for your help